# Add sequence number to query results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Access 2010 to process student discipline information data.

For some incidents there are multiple offenders. In my source data each offender has their own row.  I need my query to return an Offender number (1, 2, 3) who were involved in the incident.

The data is in a single table each row has a unique key tying it to the rest of the database.

Source Table:

```
incidentid_uk    |    personid_uk    |   uniquekey 
-------------------------------------
3001             |    1234           |    1
3002             |    1235           |    2
3002             |    1236           |    3
3002             |    1237           |    4
3003             |    1238           |    5
3004             |    1239           |    6
3005             |    1234           |    7
```

Desired Result:

```
incidentid_uk    |    personid_uk    |    sequence
-------------------------------------
3001             |    1234           |    1
3002             |    1235           |    1
3002             |    1236           |    2
3002             |    1237           |    3
3003             |    1238           |    1
3004             |    1239           |    1
3005             |    1234           |    1
```

Comment: not clear what you want?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Give examples of your input tables as well that will produce your result. That will help. From what I see you look at something that will give you something similar to SQL's `Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY incidentid_uk ORDER BY incidentid_uk)` check if there is similar functions in Access 2010

Comment: I don't have the sequence number.  I need to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access, you can get this information using a correlated subquery:

```
select incidentid_uk, personid_uk,
       (select count(*)
        from table as t2
        where t2.incidentid_uk = t.incidentid_uk and
              t2.personid_uk <= t.personid_uk
       ) as sequence
from table as t;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly on my smaller table (of 202 victim records)  Access seems to lock up for a good while on the much larger offender table.  
Thanks so much for a great answer!

Comment: Any idea why this breaks Access on a ~29,000 record table?

Comment: Yes.  Correlated subqueries are yucky.  An index on `table(incendentid_uk, personid_uk)` should help the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the same result in a report...

https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Summing-in-reports-ad4e310d-64e9-4699-8d33-b8ae9639fbf4#bmrunningsum